# What kind of newline character is in my multiline string literal?

Tags: swift, string, multiline, string-literals

I'm trying to replace a new line with something, or remove it, but I can't even figure out what kind of new line character it is. I've tried \n and \r as a regular expression:

```
var testStr =
"""
    .db $82, $14, $2c, $62, $26, $10, $28, $80, $04
    .db $82, $14, $2c, $62, $26, $10, $28, $80, $04
    .db $82, $08, $1e, $5e, $18, $60, $1a, $80, $04
    .db $82, $08, $1e, $5e, $18, $60, $1a, $86, $04
    .db $83, $1a, $18, $16, $84, $14, $1a, $18, $0e, $0c
    .db $16, $83, $14, $20, $1e, $1c, $28, $26, $87
    .db $24, $1a, $12, $10, $62, $0e, $80, $04, $04
    .db $00
"""

testStr = testStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "^\\r*", with: "!", options: .regularExpression)
testStr = testStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "^\\n*", with: "!", options: .regularExpression)

print(testStr) // does not replace new lines
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are using the beginning anchor "^" followed by the character which would only match at the beginning of a line. Have you tried removing "^" from the regex?

Comment: Looks like `CRLF`

Comment: @MYousefi, removing the "^" matches every character.

Comment: @aheze can I match CRLF with "^\\r\\n*"? It seems to not catch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've made the RegEx a little more complicated than it needs to be. As mentioned in the comments, you can remove the beginning anchor `^` and the `*`. The newline characters the multiline literals creates are caught by `\n`

Also, remember that your indentation matters with multiline string literals. You want the ending `"""` to be at the level at which the text is indented.

```
var testStr =
"""
.db $82, $14, $2c, $62, $26, $10, $28, $80, $04
.db $82, $14, $2c, $62, $26, $10, $28, $80, $04
.db $82, $08, $1e, $5e, $18, $60, $1a, $80, $04
.db $82, $08, $1e, $5e, $18, $60, $1a, $86, $04
.db $83, $1a, $18, $16, $84, $14, $1a, $18, $0e, $0c
.db $16, $83, $14, $20, $1e, $1c, $28, $26, $87
.db $24, $1a, $12, $10, $62, $0e, $80, $04, $04
.db $00
"""

testStr = testStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "!", options: .regularExpression)

print(testStr)
```

Yields:

> .db $82, $14, $2c, $62, $26, $10, $28, $80, $04!.db $82, $14, $2c, $62, $26, $10, $28, $80, $04!.db $82, $08, $1e, $5e, $18, $60, $1a, $80, $04!.db $82, $08, $1e, $5e, $18, $60, $1a, $86, $04!.db $83, $1a, $18, $16, $84, $14, $1a, $18, $0e, $0c!.db $16, $83, $14, $20, $1e, $1c, $28, $26, $87!.db $24, $1a, $12, $10, $62, $0e, $80, $04, $04!.db $00